# How to print help form Schematics?

Tags: command-line-interface, angular-schematics

Is there a built-in method for printing formatted CLI help message using Angular Schematics. I'm thinking of something something like Yargs would produce, for example.

```
schematics @my-schematic --help
```

The "--help" option just prints the help of the main schematics CLI. However, I want to print custom help message based on the schema.json of my custom schematic.

Is there a way to do this? I don't see anything like this in the API.